# GeoServer and PostgreSQL materialized views

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, sql-view

I use PostgreSQL10+ PostGIS + pgbouncer and GeoServer 2.18 Linux Ubuntu.The PostgreSQL store is the "traditional" one, not JNDI.
The database has materialized views which data I successfuly display on a map (OWS/WFS GeoJSON). The problem appears after any of materialized views update:

I have to restart db AND GeoServer to be able to get connection and data from db.
I would like to avoid this restarts of course.

[image: store settings]

Error :

````
Unable to obtain connection: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
Timeout waiting for idle object```
````

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: @IanTurton, do You mean geotools developer or geoserver developer?

Comment: Either will do, in this case probably GEOTOOLS is better.